# node-sass not recognizing all @import

Tags: sass

I started to organize my sass code into folders. I initially started with `main.scss` and my folder structure is as follows:
[image]

I was able to successfully cut and paste the variables into the `abstracts/_variables.scss` file and the base code into the `base/_base.scss` file and I have imported them like so into my `main.scss`:

```
@import 'abstracts/functions';
@import 'abstracts/mixins';
@import 'abstracts/variables';

@import 'base/animations';
@import 'base/base';
@import 'base/typography';
@import 'base/utilities';

@import 'components/button';

@import 'pages/home';
```

The rest of them however, do not successfully import. I am wondering if there is an issue with my `node-sass` script:

```
"scripts": {
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w"
  },
```

Not sure why two of my sass files import successfully and the rest will not.

Comment: Do you mean you get an error message when compiling? If so, what does it say? If not, are you sure you're including the files that contain the mixins before you try to include them somewhere?

Comment: what version of `node-sass` are you running?

Comment: @Daniel, I am running version 4.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try this, I know that version 4.5.3 does work if you are setting this up correctly. So, please uninstall node-sass with:

```
npm uninstall node-sass --save-dev
```

Then install version `4.5.3` with;

`npm install node-sass@4.5.3 --save-dev`